# KVM + QEMU + Memory = Nightmare

Tags: debian, kvm-virtualization, cache

I have this memory situation in my debian9.9

```
root@ghds-prod-3:~# free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          16035        7821         527        7294        7685         648
Swap:          4767        1731        3036
```

In this host server I have this guests on KVM+QMEMU

```
-- vm1
        cpu:  1
        mem:  512

-- vm2
        cpu:  1
        mem:  1024

-- vm3
        cpu:  1
        mem:  1024

-- vm4
        cpu:  1
        mem:  1024

-- vm5
        cpu:  1
        mem:  1024

-- vm6
        cpu:  1
        mem:  1024

-- vm7
        cpu:  1
        mem:  1024

-- vm8
        cpu:  1
        mem:  1024
```

Ok. If I want to reclaim more ram to new guest happen two things

- The system can't memory allocation
- OOM kill a VM because not enough ram to work

I try to release cache with this

```
root@ghds-prod-3:~# /bin/sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

But he does nothing.

Ok, I other host I change the cache method of disk from "none" to "directsync"   to prevent the host from caching guest disk but is early to know if work

Comment: at first i only see that you have round about 50% ram used, however i aint know why you choosen such small swap, but i if those VM's are all the same, i would suggest to use containers if all are linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use KVM and want to overcommit memory you can try to enable “kernel same-page merging” (KSM) in the linux kernel on the hypervisor.

Depending on the (mix of) guest OS’s and the loads they generate  that can allow you some leeway in overcommitting memory

Install the [`ksmtuned`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/ksmtuned) package to help you configure and control ksm